# Rails / Unobtrusive Javascript - link_to_remote :update

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, render

After looking around (a lot) I've dug through numerous posts on the subject, but I'm really confused since this issue seems to mainly have been addressed a while back (when the change happened) and rarely matches how things are looking today.

So, I'm trying to update a Rails  2.1 app to 3.2 - and ran into the deprecated link_to_remote function. I realise that it's replaced by link_to :remote => true, but that doesn't really answer my problem.

The app I'm working on is using a lot of the prototype magic to do it's in-page rendering, like the following:

In /acl/main.html.erb:

```
<table width=95%>
<tr><td align=center valign=top width=30%> <!-- Employees List -->

    <%= render(:partial => "employee_list") %>


</td><td align=center valign=top> <!-- Roles & Privileges List -->

    <div id='roles' style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #ddd;">
    <% if @employee.blank? %>
        <h4>Select employee to see access details.</h4>
    <% elsif @show_uploads %>
        <%= render :partial => 'employee_uploads' %>
    <% else %>
        <%= render :partial => 'employee_edit' %>
    <% end %>
    </div>

</td></tr>
```

And then, in acl/_employee_list.html.erb:

```
<span class="simple">
<table class="production_list">

<tr>
    <th colspan=10>
    Employees &nbsp 
    <% if @show_all %>
        <%= link_to 'Show only active', {:action => "main"} %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to 'Show inactive', {:action => "main", :show_all => 1} %>
    <% end %>
    &nbsp 
    <%= link_to_remote  'Create',
                { :url => {:action => "create_employee"}, :update => 'roles' } %>

    </th>
</tr>
<tr class="default_header_row">
    <th width=50 class="default_header_cell small_08">Initials</th>
    <th width=190 class="default_header_cell small_08">Name</th>
    <th width=90 class="default_header_cell small_08">Access</th>
</tr>

<%= render(:partial => "employee_item", :collection => @employees) %>

</table> 
</span>
```

acl/_employee_create.html.erb is just a long table of inputs, which obviously get's inserted into the #post div on the page.

So, my question is - **how do I go about getting this running with UJS in rails 3.2?**

I've got the default jquery-rails in my gemfile, but I can't seem to find out where to handle the ajax call, and to be honest, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to fix this (especially in a more general way). The application goes by this behaviour all over the place, so I need to come up with some sort of solution that mimics the previous - sort of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to keep prototype I would suggest to use both prototype and jquery.

Make sure you application.js has something like:

```
//= require prototype
//= require .....//other prototype libraries
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= ......//Ohter libraries


//Then add this to avoid any conflicts
jQuery.noConflict();
$j = jQuery;
```

You can use $j when you want to do something with jquery and $ for prototype

Now if you just override link_to_remote method in your application helper so that it renders something like

```
link_to "TEXT",  URL, :remote=> true, options
```

And

```
Use a js.erb file instead of render :text=>'blah blah'
```

Thats all, I guess

The following has something in details:
[more details](http://www.cowboycoded.com/2010/07/20/replacing-link_to_remote-with-ujs-in-rails-3-prototype/)

Comment: Right, i think I'd prefer to flip away from prototype, and move it all to jQuery. So, if i wanted to make a solution for that specific page, where would the js go? Like, do i put the heavy lifting into application.js like:
`$(#roles).update(response);`
Or does that fit in a specific file?

Comment: EDIT: Okay i read the page, so I'll refactor my question:
Can i make this general? Like, if i don't wanna do an explicit `$(#someid).update(respones)` for every single link_to_remote that i have, is there a way to do it a little less targeted?

Comment: as I mentioned:
Use a js.erb file instead of render :text=>'blah blah' as js response.

for example:
  you have a link:
  <%= link_to 'Latest Comments', latest_comments_path, :remote: true%>

  it goes to index action of comments controller. then to handle ajax response you have to have index.js.erb file in /views/comments/ directory with the content like:

  $('comments').append('render partial: 'comment', collection: @comments)

etc.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

in /acl/main.html.erb:  (assuming your routes file has an employees_path)

`<%= link_to employees_path, remote:true %>`

in /acl/employees/index.js.erb:

`<%= for employee in @employees %>
  $('table tbody').append(<%= j raw render('employee', employee:employee))
<% end %>`

Comment: That wasn't the part of the code I was interested in, and there is the difference that I'm interested in the content of the ajax, so I needed the binding. The resource in the answer, allthough it was meant for some prototype/jQuery hybrid setup actually ended up fixing things, so I'm accepting that :)

Thanks anyway